# How can I store integer values in xam.plugin.settings?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have always used the settings plugin by James in my xamarin forms projects but I have always stored string values. Now I have a reason to want to store integer values in settings. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Your integer.ToString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
public class AppSettings
{        
    private static ISettings Settings => CrossSettings.Current;

    public static int Age
    {
        get => Settings.GetValueOrDefault(nameof(Age), 0);

        set => Settings.AddOrUpdateValue(nameof(Age), value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class AppSettings
{
    private static ISettings Settings => CrossSettings.Current;

```
private static string PhoneNumberKey = "PhoneNumberKey";
public static int PhoneNumber
{
    get => Settings.GetValueOrDefault(nameof(PhoneNumberKey), 0);

    set => Settings.AddOrUpdateValue(nameof(PhoneNumberKey), value);
}
```

}